# Adding all the values of the column based on column Header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have three columns of data for each month. I have concatenated each month name with column name now my columns names looks like

```
ST41804
SVYM total41804
```

For example, Now i have to find out the sum of column SVYM total in june month. 
i ll find the  location of the column by using the formula (i.e.MATCH(CONCATENATE("SVYM Total","Jun-14"),Array,0).

Now how to add all the values of the column which i found out by using match formula.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A4:Z100,0,MATCH("SVYM Total" & "Jun-14",Array,0)))
```

where your data (*excluding* headers) are in range `A4:Z100`. I supposed that `Array` is named range that refers to, in my example, `A3:Z3`.